# jQuery run script after

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination, tablesorter

I have a problem with the load of a js action, i have these two lines:

```
$(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
$(".sorter td:last-child").css("text-align", "center").css("padding", "0").css("line-height", "0").css("width", "65px");
```

This working oke... but when i go to the second page of the tablesorter pager plugin then it is not loading again.

**Screenshot:**
[a busy cat http://www.dreamwire.nl/Cleanished/error.jpg](http://www.dreamwire.nl/Cleanished/error.jpg)

Can somewone help me with this? This is all the JS what i have:

```
var $sorterTable = $(".sorter");
var tablesorterConfig = { widgets: ['zebra'], headers:{ 0:{sorter:false} } };
tablesorterConfig.headers[$sorterTable.find("thead th").length - 1] = { sorter:false };

$sorterTable
.tablesorter(tablesorterConfig)          
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, size : 5 });

$(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
$(".sorter td:last-child").css("text-align", "center").css("padding", "0").css("line-height", "0").css("width", "65px");
```

Comment: `$(".sorter td:last-child").css("text-align", "center").css("padding", "0").css("line-height", "0").css("width", "65px");` could be shortened, somewhat, to: `$(".sorter td:last-child").css({"text-align": "center","padding": "0", "line-height": "0", "width": "65px"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these scripts do is set styles.  Why not just put those in your stylesheet?

```
.sorter td:first-child {
    width: 13px;
}
.sorter td:first-child + td + td + td + td + td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    width: 65px;
}
```

Comment: Because last-child is not working with IE 6, IE 7 and IE 8 in CSS.

Comment: @Maanstraat - See the code example in my answer.  You can do this without the last-child selector by using first-child and adjacent sibling selectors.  These are CSS2 selectors and work in older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Version 2.0.7 of the Tablesorter plugin includes the `pagerChange` and `pagerComplete` events.  If you are using this version (or if it's possible for you to upgrade) you can reapply your styles on the `pagerComplete` event. http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#Events

```
$(".sorter").bind('pagerComplete', function() {
    // reapply styles here...
    $(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
    $(".sorter td:last-child").css({"text-align": "center","padding": "0", "line-height": "0", "width": "65px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set those css styles after clicking on pager also. Try this

```
var $sorterTable = $(".sorter");
var tablesorterConfig = { widgets: ['zebra'], headers:{ 0:{sorter:false} } };
tablesorterConfig.headers[$sorterTable.find("thead th").length - 1] = { sorter:false };

$sorterTable
.tablesorter(tablesorterConfig)          
.tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false, size : 5 });

$("#pager").click(function(){
  $(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
  $(".sorter td:last-child").css({"text-align": "center","padding": "0", "line-height": "0", "width": "65px"});
});

$(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
  $(".sorter td:last-child").css({"text-align": "center","padding": "0", "line-height": "0", "width": "65px"});
```

Comment: Hi ShankarSangoli, i have put it in but it won't work. :-(..

This is working:
`$("#pager .first, #prev .last, #pager .next, #pager .last,, #pager select").click(function(){`

Only the selectbox won't update when you select more rows.

Comment: try changing it to $("#pager img").click(function(){
  $(".sorter td:first-child").css("width", "13px");
  $(".sorter td:last-child").css({"text-align": "center","padding": "0", "line-height": "0", "width": "65px"});
});